# I need to chart a complex dice system probabilities: how to compute them?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Short intro for readers that plays old boardgames: we're talking about ***Silent Death*** dice system.

Long intro:
I roll 3 dice, each of them can be a 4,6,8,10 or 12 faces die. Lets call **H** the sum of them all.
There's 3 other values i can calculate: *(i'm trying to define them with my poor english, pls be patient :) )*

- **A**: the sum of the lowest values rolled
- **B**: the sum of the middle values rolled
- **C**: the sum of the higher values rolled

*Examples:*

```
roll is 2, 5, 9
 - A = 2
 - B = 5
 - C = 9
 - H = 16

roll is 5, 5, 9
 - A = 10 ('cause there's 2 "lowest" values (5) )
 - B = 10 ('cause there's 2 "middle" values (5) )
 - C = 9
 - H = 19

roll is 2, 5, 5
 - A = 2 
 - B = 10 ('cause there's 2 "middle" values (5) )
 - C = 10 ('cause there's 2 "highest" values (5) )
 - H = 12

roll is 5, 5, 5
 - A = 15
 - B = 15
 - C = 15
 - H = 15
```

I need to build a spreadsheet to chart **A**, **B**, **C** and **H** chances given the 3 dice faces.

How do I calculate that probabilities?

*(If you can write the answer also in excel formula, other than in math expressions, it will be really apreciated* :)

-edit-

*This just 'cause i understand more that format than math symbols, not to make you do my work )*

Comment: What do you mean by “the sum of the middle values?” is it the sum of the rolls minus $A$ and $B$?

Comment: No. When the rolls show three different numbers, and you want the middle one, B = H-A-C. But there's more, which is what i tried to show in the example. When the roll show 2 equal numbers, and you need the "middle" value (B), you have to sum the pair, 'cause the roll result is considered to have "no minimum" or "no maximum". The same happens when you have to pick A or C: in case of 2 equal numbers, if the third is higher then A is the sum of the pair, if the third is lower then C is the sum of the pair. With a roll with three equal numbers, A,B and C are all equal to H.

Comment: @amd : Trying to be more clear, this is an edited exerpt from an english rulebook:  
`
    Lowest (A): equals the lowest number rolled. In case of ties, add all the low numbers together. If all three dice are the same, total them.
    Middle (B): Damage equals the middle number rolled. In case of ties (in which case, there is no middle number), add the tie numbers together. If all three dice are the same, total them.
    Highest (C): Damage equals the highest number rolled. In case of ties, add all the high numbers together. If all three dice are the same, total them.`